# WPF Prism: Problem with creating a Shell

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I just started learning Prism and trying to use it with MEF in a test WPF application.
Based on *"WPF Hands-On Lab: Get Started with the Prism
Library"* example in the *Prism4* documentation, in a test WPF project I renamed **MainWindow** class to **Shell**. 
My Bootstrapper class has the following code (also based on the Lab example):

```
class Bootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
         return new Shell();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Shell)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
    ...
```

App.xaml.cs code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app even without exporting any module in it, I get an error:
**"Cannot locate resource 'mainwindow.xaml'."**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks to @Shiraz Bhaiji I found out that my App.xaml still has the attribute `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` It should be deleted. And this is pointed out in the above mentioned Prism4 documentation: "Open the App.xaml file and remove the attribute StartupUri. Because you are manually instantiating the shell
window in your bootstrapper, this attribute is not required." I just missed this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you renamed your class did mainwindow.xaml get renamed to shell.xaml?

But the code/config is still pointing to the original name.

Comment: Yes, my mainwindow.xaml get renamed to shell.xaml. And do you mean App.xaml string StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"? Yes, after deleting it the error's gone. Thank you! +1

Comment: HAd the same issue, am presently setting up the PRISM WPF enterprise level app! going through all possible hurdles met by others! too bad, i couldnt mark ur comment as answer